# Adding a foreign key constraint back to a Django table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a job that does some work on a copy of a table corresponding to a Django model, and then replaces the working table with the copy when done.

The problem is that although the copy of the table picks up all of the indexes and everything else, it's not picking up the foreign key constraints.

Can I just add them back when I swap the table in?  Or does South or Django depend on anything in the constraint name?

I'm on MySQL and Django 1.8.

(Let's assume I'm not able to change how the job works)

Comment: How is the copy being created? If you cant edit the job doing the work on the copy itself, can you edit the process that makes the copy?

Comment: May you describe more or at least write a sample code?